# How to skip x axis labels in d3.js chart dynamically to have always a pretty chart?

Tags: d3.js

how do I skip x axis labels in d3.js chart dynamically to have always a pretty chart?
If I have a chart with lots of data points on the x axis and thererfore for each data point is a label on the x axis and these labels do overlap.
Here is an example [overlapping x axis labels](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html)

I do not want to rotate the x axis labels I would like to skip the display of labels if there a maybe more than 20 on the x axis to have always a pretty chart.

Answer (score 2):

Referring the example you have put on screen shot:

```
//you draw the graph when ticks are less than 10 add this condition
 if (x.ticks().length < 10){
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3PpwXH6FHHqkgbWR0dQx?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Set tickValues to your xAxis.

xAxis.tickValues(d3.range(minX, maxX, interval));

interval is the number of skips. Like if you want to display every 5th label on your xAxis then interval would be 5.