# Skip NULL Label on x-axis in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am plotting a bar chart where in data i have StartOfMonth and a Value. now some of the StartOfMonth values are NULL and other has a date specified where as all the values are present using which i am plotting the bar. Now on x-axis labels, i only want to labels where StartOfMonth has a Value but i am getting one NULL value at second point. I have not used any formula to skip other NULL values. Bars of NULL values must show, they should not be removed

Here is my data that i am trying to Show

```
var data = 
        [
  {
    "Date": "1/3/2017",
    "Value": 0.0577372,
    "Close_Price": 58.538,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "Jan, 2017"
  },
  {
    "Date": "1/4/2017",
    "Value": 0.0515099,
    "Close_Price": 58.2761,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "1/5/2017",
    "Value": 0.0503642,
    "Close_Price": 58.2761,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "1/6/2017",
    "Value": 0.058741,
    "Close_Price": 58.7812,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },{
    "Date": "2/1/2017",
    "Value": 0.0496128,
    "Close_Price": 59.4734,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "FEB, 2017"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2/2/2017",
    "Value": 0.0414615,
    "Close_Price": 59.0899,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2/3/2017",
    "Value": 0.049448,
    "Close_Price": 59.5669,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
{
    "Date": "3/1/2017",
    "Value": 0.057454,
    "Close_Price": 61.1125,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "March, 2017"
  },
  {
    "Date": "3/2/2017",
    "Value": 0.0404411,
    "Close_Price": 60.2373,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "3/3/2017",
    "Value": 0.0437129,
    "Close_Price": 60.4631,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "3/6/2017",
    "Value": 0.0431221,
    "Close_Price": 60.4819,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
{
    "Date": "4/3/2017",
    "Value": 0.0454515,
    "Close_Price": 61.6865,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "4/4/2017",
    "Value": 0.0474509,
    "Close_Price": 61.8559,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  },
  {
    "Date": "4/5/2017",
    "Value": 0.0435526,
    "Close_Price": 61.6959,
    "StockSymbol": "MSFT",
    "StartOfMonth": "NULL"
  }
];
```

here is the graph i am getting
[image]

Comment: What if you set it to `null` instead of `"NULL"`?

Comment: Same result. Now i get "null" at second point instead of "NULL"

Comment: Actually  when i changed it into null instead of string "NULL" , its shows second point just empty. Rest is same

Comment: What value are you wanting there?

Comment: i do not want to show any value there. i just want to skip the label where the value is null. it should not be empty or return NULL

Comment: May be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407263/how-to-skip-x-axis-labels-in-d3-js-chart-dynamically-to-have-always-a-pretty-cha

Answer (score 1):

If you have an xAxis element, you could filter all the null values and remove them:

Something like:

```js
xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)) // xScale being your scale
xAxis.selectAll('text').filter((t) => t.text() === "NULL").remove()
```